# Complicated QoS Settings

Tags: wireless-networking, gaming, qos

Hi guys I need some help. My whole family uses the same router and when I try to play online games I encounter high ping due to my brother and sister watching Netflix, Youtube etc. I did some research and found that this problem may be prevented with QoS. But when I connected the router's interface, those options looked so complicated compared to other routers interfaces that I found on the internet. Could anyone help me figure this out? Thanks.

https://i.hizliresim.com/2BzPtG.png

https://i.hizliresim.com/sjzZzR.png

https://i.hizliresim.com/kufaxx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are multiple queues on your device. Im guessing all the traffic is put in queue 0 by default. So you need to add a configuration that will put the traffic coming from your PC into another queue.

```
1. On this screen: https://i.hizliresim.com/sjzZzR.png
   Tick the checkbos enable
   add the mac address of your device (PC/Tablet LAN or WiFi interface)
2. On this screen: https://i.hizliresim.com/kufaxx.png
   Put it into another queue than the rest of the traffic
   Save
```

QoS will most probably only help you to prioritize traffic on the WAN side of your router. What im saying is: if you are gaming via Wireless, then this settings wont help you much im afraid. There is a QoS implementation in Wireless called WMM, but this is usually not implemented in home devices like yours. Enabling it brings down the troughput of your Wifi as well.

Comment: Hi Mario. Thanks for taking your time and answering my question. I am not currently at home but I will give it a try when I return. Have a nice day.